# Disabling back button when user logs out

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to disallow user to go back page after logging out

I mean after he log out browsers back button should be disabled or something like that

even after ending the session, pressing back button takes him to back page...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961188/disable-browsers-back-button

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

http://strcpy.com/111