# How to disable browser backbutton

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable browser's back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961188/disable-browsers-back-button)

I have a log in page

```
<div style="border:1px red;margin:150px 0px 0px 0px;text-align:center;">
UserName :<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
Password &nbsp:<asp:TextBox ID="txtpass" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Signin" /><br />
asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
/div>
```

I want to disable back button o this page using ASP.NET.

Comment: I think you will find two things: 1) disabling the back button is not easily done, and 2) it is generally considered a *very bad* idea to disable expected behavior in the web browser.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you want javascript code then try this

```
script type = "text/javascript" >
 function disableBackButton()
 {
 window.history.forward();
 }
 setTimeout("disableBackButton()", 0);
 /script>
```

cheers

Comment: With this code you set a very bad load to the browser to call with out breath this function. This can cache a lot of problems to your user and make you page behave slow.

Comment: @Aristos i dont think so

Comment: @ranjenanil the setTimeout creates a time, a new thread, that is call again and again the same function. a waist of resource. There are other methods to solve the issue of the re-post the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in ASP.NET.

You may be able to achieve similar results, either by forcing the browser to navigate forward

```
javascript:window.history.forward(1);
```

or by including your login page in a frameset and forcing the parent frame to reload the login page.

```
<frameset onUnload="location.replace(self.location)">
```