# The page is not same when browser back button is clicked

Tags: asp.net, caching, browser, browser-cache

I have a gridview control in my `default.aspx` page, and in page_load of this control, I populate this gridview.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grd_UserOrderList.DataSource = UserOrderListData.GetOrderList();
        grd_UserOrderList.DataBind();
    }
```

What happens is that when I enter `default.aspx` page, I see 4 items in my gridview, I enter one of the items, and then click back button of the browser, I see 2 items. I checked the page_load function and it is not fired when back button is clicked. When I click refresh, again there is 4 items. I have this problem when working in my computer, but when I publish my project to server, I didn't have the same problem. What could be the **reason**? I am not looking for a temporary fix like disabling cache. I am using ie9 as browser.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961188/disable-browsers-back-button

Comment: Doesn't provide an answer for the "Reasons" that cache is not working as I expected, I am tring to find the root cause to fix the root.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 
[How to Refresh Page when called via the Back Button](http://www.mrc-productivity.com/techblog/?p=1235)

Or you can try this.

We could disable the page cache. Then if we click the back button in the browser, the page will re-execute the page_load event to refresh the page.

The code is shown below.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
                Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
                Response.Expires = -1441;
            }
            Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
```

This also might help you.

```
<script language="JavaScript">

  javascript:window.history.forward(1);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am not looking for an alternative fix, I am look for the reason why cache is not working as expected.

Comment: Because there will be cache in browser and the previous page will be present in the cache so for performance it loads. so pageload will not be executed.