# hide browser back button in the button click

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net

I have a vb .net application in which i'm using a user control for the user registration. This user control has 3 buttons and three asp panels. In each button click corresponding panel will be shown. I need to hide the browser back button functionality only in the 3rd button click. How can i do it? Anyone please help me.

I have tried by putting this line of script in the aspx page which contains the user control.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.history.forward();
</script>
```

But it didnt work for me.

Comment: Disabling browser functionality is usually a bad idea, and aggravates users to no end.  What's wrong with using the back button?  If the user requests a previous step in this process, can't you just direct them back to the current step from server-side code?  Ideally it would be an even better user experience to have the entire registration process take place in a single page by showing/hiding elements dynamically, which would remove the back button from the picture entirely.

Comment: I agree, a web application should be able to handle the back button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable browser's back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961188/disable-browsers-back-button)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.history.forward();

    function noBack() {
        window.history.forward();
    }
</script>

<BODY onload="noBack();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">
```

check the [**DEMO**](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/javascript-disable-browser-back-button/noback.html) here.

On searching, many geek suggest that this kind of behavior is not good for browser.

Comment: more details here: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/

;-)

Comment: @bnz yup.  You added the link when I was editing. So left it to you :)