# Safari Browser Back button issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

After logout browser should not allow to go back when user clicks on browser back button. This functionality is working fine in IE, FF but not working in Safari. Tryied a lot but not able to solve. Here is the code that i have used.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   window.location.hash="";
   window.location.hash="";
   window.onhashchange=function(){
window.location.hash="";
   } 
});
```

Comment: This seems like kind of weird way of doing it. Also feels like a case for infinite recursion in some browsers. Changing the hash within onhashchange

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961188/disable-browsers-back-button

Answer (score 0):

You can Disable safari browser back button if above trick is not working for you.
try this to disable back button-

```
   function noBack(){window.history.forward();}
   noBack();
   window.onload=noBack;
   window.onpageshow=function(evt){if(evt.persisted)noBack();}
   window.onunload=function(){void(0);}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing feedback. This i have already tried, not working in safari browser.