# Browser Back button should not work

Tags: c#, asp.net

My problem is Once i logged-in into an application, and pressed browser's back button, then Login-page displays. Now when i click over browser's forward button, then all the caches should be cleared, no one can use Application's any page.
I have used these three statements, but where to use, I dont know ??

```
Session["UserName"] = null;
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Edit:
Once i logged-in into the page, and when i press browser's Back then i should not be able to go forward, either by code or by disabling browser forward button.

Comment: you want to disable browser backbutton functionality or add the code ? specify your requirement? if your requirement is disable browser back button follow this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961188/disable-browsers-back-button)