# How to disable back and front button of browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable back and front button of browsers. I have tried with the following code and  Iam using onload for div tag and div tag id is **order**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var back= noback();
         $("#order").load("back");
         function noback() {
        window.history.forward(-1);
        alert('backbtn');
      }
  setTimeout("noback()", 0);    
  alert('loading');
});
</script>
```

When i tested, alert backbtn is working fine but i can navigate to back page. Please help me how to make disable those buttons.

Comment: **forget it.**.Do not disable expected browser behaviour

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961188/disable-browsers-back-button.

Answer (score 2):

That would not be a good approach to disable the browser back button rather you should add code to handle the functionality as to what happens when the user clicks on back button.

On approach could be to place this script in the head section of the page so as to dont allow the user to visit the page again

```
<script>
  function restrictback(){window.history.forward();}
  setTimeout("restrictback()", 0);
  window.onunload=function(){null};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    window.history.forward();
    function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="noBack();"
    onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">
```

Comment: here in the code Iam using div tag for onload..@smruthi

Comment: onload function doesnt work on div. The onload event can only be used on the document(body) itself, frames, images, and scripts. In other words, it can be attached to only body and/or each external resource. The div is not an external resource and it's loaded as part of the body, so the onload event doesn't apply there. CHeck this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div

Comment: yes i know..i have seen this previously Smruthi..for that reason Iam giving id for div tag and using the id in $("#order").load("back"); Please have a look at my code.