# Disable backspace not working when focus in Select

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to prevent backspace from navigating back to the previous page with my code

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {

    if (e.keyCode === 8) {

        alert("Backspace is pressed");

        e.preventDefault;
        return false;

    } else {

    }

});
```

It's working except when I focus on a `select` tag then press backspace it ignores the function I created.

Comment: Can you post fiddle with little bit explanation?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961188/disable-browsers-back-button)

The code:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {

  var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (key == 8 /*BACKSPACE*/ || key == 46/*DELETE*/) {
    var len=window.location.href.length;
    if(window.location.href[len-1]!='#') window.location.href += "#";
  }
},false);
```

[JSFIDDLER](http://jsfiddle.net/3vrcgL11/)