# Disable browser back button event in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Can anybody tell me meaning of below code.

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function preventBack() { window.history.forward(); }
    setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
    window.onunload = function () { null };

</script>
```

Comment: setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);means call preventBack() function on delay of 0 second.I have one doubt,does function get call everytime.Means continous...

Comment: see this page for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961188/disable-browsers-back-button

Comment: The forward() method loads the next URL in the history list. setTimeout(func|code, delay) means its delay of 0 seconds http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval