# How does gmail handle its back button after the user has logged out?

Tags: javascript

I've seen that on logging out one can not go back to inbox on pressing a back button. How does gmail achieve that without disabling back button or clearing browser cache ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable browser's back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961188/disable-browsers-back-button)

Comment: Gmail does not disables its back button.

Answer (score 0):

`cache` expires when you click on `logout`. so you cannot go to the inbox using back button.