# How to disable the back button without relying on Javascript?

Tags: asp.net, security

I've seen some web sites like banking applications that prevent the user from using the back button. If I remember correctly, when you press the back button your session times out.

How can I do this?

Comment: Let me recommend Post/Redirect/Get pattern use <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get>.  Besides that just build in some safe guards for double posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, don't do that; don't surprise the user.  The back button is there so it can be used.  If that's a problem for you, find a way around it, not prevent it.

Use the `Post/Redirect/Get` pattern @benjynito mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You cant disable browser's back button just use that, I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533867/whats-the-best-method-for-forcing-cache-expiration-in-asp-net)

```
Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Comment: Some explanation of what this does and why the OP should use it would be helpful.