# How to Expire cache

Tags: asp.net

I am using cache to store the data but in some operations such as addition/updation I want to reload the i am using following method but it does not works, is there any other solution

```
Response.Cache.SetSlidingExpiration(true);
```

also tried

```
cache["MoiveLIst"] = null;
```

but no result

Above code should make the if condition true but it does not, and if block does not executes because cache is not null, how i can make it null

```
if(Cache ["MovieList"]==null)                  
{
     Cache.Insert("MovieList", _client.GetAllMovies(), null, timespane, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
}
List<Movie> oData = Cache["MovieList"] as List<Movie>;
```

Comment: related to [What's the best method for forcing cache expiration in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533867/whats-the-best-method-for-forcing-cache-expiration-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [Cache.Remove Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.remove.aspx) before inserting

```
if(Cache["MoiveLIst"] != null)
  Cache.Remove("MoiveLIst");

Cache.Insert("MovieList", _client.GetAllMovies(), null, timespane, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
List<Movie> oData = Cache["MovieList"] as List<Movie>;
```