# Prevent backspace from navigating back in asp.net web form

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I have an asp.net web form with some read only fields. My issue is that if the user selects the read only textbox and presses the backspace to try and delete the content in the textbox, it goes back a page in the form. I am using IE 11 and can't seem to find a working solution for this issue. Could someone provide me with some advice as to how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at this post?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533867/whats-the-best-method-for-forcing-cache-expiration-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to prevent the `keydown` event for `readonly` inputs. Try the following

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[readonly]');
for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs.item(i).onkeydown = function(e) {
        if (e.which === 8) return false;
    };
}
```

Note that `8` is the keycode for <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>.